# Does YouTube Android Player API have a quota?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I was planning on using the [Youtube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), when I noticed it needs a [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/%20YouTube%20Data%20API%20%28v3%29), API key: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register

The Youtube Data API handles most youtube's interaction, like getRating, upload video's, rate video's , get playlists etc, and sets a quota based on those actions: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota & https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

None of these actions are video playback though, that's what the Android Player does. I also can't find anything about quotas on the Android Player API section.

So, my question is two-fold: Why does the player API need the Data API, and is there a quota on usage of the player API?

Comment: Is SO a good place to ask such questions? Maybe you should write to YouTube/Google support about this?

Comment: SO is The place youtube refers to to ask questions. "Ask a Question" on the Youtube API page links directly to StackOverflow, and then there's this: http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/14/youtube-moves-api-discussions-and-support-to-stack-overflow-ditches-google-groups/

Comment: Right, but this particular question is about how a third-party service works. It cannot be answered unless a person is representative of that service provider or digs out the information for you.

Comment: @ThomQ did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have researched on this.
The Google Developers Console allows creation of keys and then we **restrict** the key usage ourselves. This means that each key when created is a **general key**. It can be used for any Google API.

As far as YouTube player is concerned. As long as we don't make any calls to the YouTube API in our app, I don't think there is a quota limit. This is what I have concluded after reading this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage

Also, since the player doesn't work until you have the YouTube app installed, it basically uses the app to play content. If you just show thumbnails, the thumbnails are already public and you can generate them this way: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

This API does not require an API key thus it does not affect the quota in any way.

This is an **intuitive** answer as per my research. I could not find any explanation anywhere so this is what I came up with.